# Better Approach for sending bulk mail using JavaMail API

Tags: smtp, jakarta-mail, email-client

Is there any better approach for sending bulk mail using JavaMail API.I use the below approach.

```
enter code here Transport tr = session.getTransport("smtp");
tr.connect(smtphost, username, password);
tr.sendMessage(msg, msg.getAllRecipients());
```

> i used to send 'n'number of mails using the same connection.
>   I is there any other separate way for sending bulk mail.Kindly help me in this for getting better solution.

Comment: my suggestion would be to use some wrapper around java mail API like Apache mail API

Answer (score 0):

In what way do you want it to be "better"?

You can use multiple threads to send more messages in parallel,
up to the limit of what your mail server will allow.

Comment: Suppose if we have different set of messages,how to send them in single push. Instead of sending one by one.

Comment: I don't understand "different set of messages".  If you want to list the recipients of the message in the To header of the message, you need to send a different message for each recipient or set of recipients.  If you don't include the recipient (which will make your message look more like spam), you can send a single message to many recipients by passing the recipients as the second argument to sendMessage.

Comment: Invoice no1 notification need to be sent to 5 member,and invoice no2 need to be sent to another set of 5 members. Suppose this is the scenario, i need to send these two different sets in single push, instead of sending them one by one by using sendMessage method. I there any way to send these messages in single push.

Comment: You can reuse the connection by calling "connect" once and then calling "sendMessage" twice, once for each of the two different messages, is that what you mean by "single push"?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Thread pooling as it gives very good performance.I have implemented and sharing you the below code snippet.

```java
try { 
    ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool("no. of threads");     
    // no. of threads is depend on your cpu/memory usage it's better to test with diff. no. of threads. 
    Runnable worker = new MyRunnable(message); 
    // message is the javax.mail.Message 
    executor.execute(worker); 
    executor.shutdown();     
    executor.awaitTermination(Long.MAX_VALUE, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS); 
}
```

Comment: Please take the time to format code in your answers properly, thanks.